# JavaFX app become unusable after print dialog

Tags: javafx, printing, kotlin

I'm displaying a [ControlsFX PopOver](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/openpss/blob/master/app/src/com/hendraanggrian/openpss/control/popover/ViewInvoicePopover.kt) for invoice, naturally its content must be printable. I have successfully print it using this code:

```
val printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter()
val layout = printer.createPageLayout(PAPER_INVOICE, PORTRAIT, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
printer.printerAttributes
val job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob()
invoiceBox.run {
    border = null
    transforms += Scale(
        layout.printableWidth / invoiceBox.boundsInParent.width,
        layout.printableHeight / invoiceBox.boundsInParent.height
    )
}
if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(invoiceBox.scene.window)) {
    val success = job.printPage(layout, invoiceBox)
    if (success) {
        job.endJob()
    }
}
```

However, the whole application becomes unusable after the printing process (even after canceling the print dialog). The main window is still there, it just can't be focused while clicking on it (or the app in the Windows taskbar) just produces error sound. Is this a known bug?

I have only tested this on Windows since I don't believe the printer I'm working with (Epson LX-310) are compatible with Mac/Linux.

Comment: What is invoiceBox.run?

Comment: It is Kotlin contract extensions. There are 4: 'run', 'let', 'also', and 'apply'

Comment: Don't think that helped, but I am going to guess it's similar to a thread. If so, try not using it.

Comment: @Sedrick No, it isn't: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html.

Comment: It turns out not to be JavaFX print API's fault. The node just need to be present when printing dialog is showing. In this case, PopOver can't be auto-hidden. Thanks for your concern and someone should close this.